# How to restrict the height of a bootstrap container

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to create a messaging page on which the text box will sit on the bottom of the page and the messages will be displayed above it. Here is my code for the page:

```
<div class="ui">

    <% @messages.each do |message| %>
            <% if message.body %>
             <% user = User.find(message.user_id) %>
                  <div class="item mt-3">   
                         <div class="list">
                           <div class="item">
                             <strong><%= user.first_name %></strong>
                                <div class="content">
                                    <%= simple_format(message.body) %>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
            <% end %>
            <% end %>






    <%= form_for [@conversation, @message], html: {class: "ui reply form"}, remote: true  do|f| %>

       <%= f.text_area :body, class: "message-box",  id: "message-form"%>

      <button type="submit", class="send-button", style="display: inline">
        <i class="nav-link fa fa-paper-plane"></i>
     </button>



     <%= f.text_field :user_id, value: current_user.id, type: "hidden" %>

    <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that this code displays like this[image]

The text is running under the text box. My instinct is to place the messages and the text box into two separate boxes and restrict the height of the top one, but I have been attempting this to no avail.

Can anybody suggest how I might be able to get this done?

Comment: checkout the documentation for [bootstrap's grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/). If you use default containers/rows/columns, not much custom css will be needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should place both in different div's and add *'max-height'* to where the text displays.

Also Im assuming this is happening because the text input field is position with *position:absolute*.
You can make both *position:relative* and make both *display:block*. If you want to align the input at the bottom of the screen just use *vertical-align*

Answer (score 0):

I also think you need to add some custom css styles to the div containing message. Like max-height: 100px and overflow-y: auto;

It would be easier to help you if you could provide fully rendered html instead of a template.